# JQplot labels cut off in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jqplot

Has anyone seen this before?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kncuH.png

It cuts of the text of the labels. You can see it in the bottom and some of the ones in the y axis. I'm using jqplot version 1.0.8 and jQuery to 1.9.1.

I tried changing the font size and mark width. But it does not help.  I have a sneaky suspicion that is has something to do with rotating text.

(The "bug" is only present in internet explorer 8 and down.)

Comment: Could you please paste the issue in a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issues, and solved it by upgrading excanvas to the latest version. I used the latest version of excanvas from the explorercanvas repository: https://explorercanvas.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/excanvas.js

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

edit: the problem is  $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer. If you don't use it, it will work.
lg Blue